# Uploading Maven reports to CI (Bamboo) server

Tags: maven, selenium, continuous-integration, bamboo

In our company, we have set up CI with Bamboo, Maven, Selenium and PhantomJS. After each successful commit-triggered build, the application is deployed and automatically tested in PhantomJS with Selenium. Unfortunately, we don't have a dedicated Mac OS X box with Safari (and don't planning to have one), but testing under Safari is very important for us. Luckily, there is a non-programmer guy with MacBook who runs Selenium tests manually, usually at the end of the day. (I mean, manually invokes Maven that executes Selenium tests; he doesn't test anything by hand in the browser.)

When tests fail, that kind guy marks the build as broken in Bamboo and mails us Surefire reports for analysis. Is it possible to take some burden off him? Ideally, the reports would be uploaded somewhere automatically, along with flagging the build in Bamboo. Is this a good/common practice? Any better suggestions?

Comment: One option would be to set up Selenium Server on MacBook and putting it into VPN together with Bamboo. Unfortunately, it couldn't be guaranteed that MacBook is on and connected each time the build happens, let alone driving the guy crazy with Safari popping up at arbitrary moments.

Comment: Did you thought about running Mac OS X inside a virtual machine?

Comment: It was the very first option we've explored. We had to reject it due to the extreme complexity of the setup process. AFAIK, no opensource hypervisor is capable of running unmodified Mac OS X out-of-the-box on a PC platform. We've seen a lot of tutorials on how to run Mac OS X in VirtualBox, but all of them required some pirate OS X repacks. Additionally, the CI server has constrained resources, and adding another 4G RAM just to have Safari running would be a bit of PITA. That said, we stick to the "nice guy with a MacBook" scenario as a poor man's alternative.